# dynamic buttons on panel1 - locations

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollable, panels

So I have an app with a scrollable panel, which lists folders dynamically on the panel. Below the folder listings, I also have a button. Once a click on the button, it dynamically creates a button next to each folder listing. My Y value for each button increases every time with =+ 26 - this all works fine if my panel is not scrollable yet. Once the panel becomes scrollable and I scroll down and then continue adding more buttons, it jumps a few spaces and then only adds more buttons. I assume it is something to do with the scrolling which changes to Y location? How can I work past this?

C# WinForms

Thanks and regards.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, (y+6));
    buttons.Add(newButton);
    y += 20;
    panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
}
```

Comment: Its due to Elven Magic!!! Jokes aside... please share some code its pretty dark to see without code!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Why do you need?   List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>(); Its not used anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your dynamic button lines with the following:

```
panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        Button myButton = new Button();
        myButton.Location = new Point(
           panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X,
           panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y + (y+6));
        y += 20;
        panel1.Controls.Add(myButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try get the y- Location of your button to dynamically from the last button: (i-1) in this example,

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button newButton = new Button();
        newButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, buttons[i -1].Location.Y + 26);
        i++;
        buttons.Add(newButton);
        panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class to create and manage the buttons e.g.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CreateButtons
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Size to create each button
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Size ButtonSize { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a reference to your buttons
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<Button> Buttons { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// base name of buttone e.g. btn, cmd etc.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ButtonBaseName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to spread out buttons
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int Base { get; set; }
    public int BaseAddition { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Count of buttons
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int ButtonCount { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// control to place buttons onto
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Control ParentControl { get; set; }
    public CreateButtons(string BaseName)
    {
        this.ButtonBaseName = BaseName;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Create single button and add it to the list of buttons property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    public void CreateSingleButton(string item)
    {
        if (Buttons == null)
        {
            Buttons = new List<Button>();
        }
        Button b = new Button
        {
            Name = string.Concat(ButtonBaseName, item),
            Text = item,
            Size = ButtonSize,
            Location = new Point(25, this.Base),
            Parent = ParentControl,
            Visible = true
        };

        // wire up an event or have an event it gets wired too
        b.Click += (object s, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            //Button tb = (Button)s;
            //MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
        };

        this.ParentControl.Controls.Add(b);
        Buttons.Add(b);
        Base += BaseAddition;
    }
}
```

In a form setup with a panel that scrolls, a listbox (to show we can get to all the buttons created), a text box to allow you to test this by giving a name for each button. A button to create a single button which gets added to a List.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CreateDynamicButtons1_cs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private CreateButtons buttons = new CreateButtons("btn");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons.ParentControl = panel1;
            buttons.Base = 10;
            buttons.BaseAddition = 35;
            buttons.ButtonSize = new Size(50, 25);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
            {
                buttons.CreateSingleButton(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (buttons.Buttons != null)
            {
                listBox1.DataSource = 
                    buttons.Buttons.Select(item => item.Name).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```